# MVC Ajax TextArea tiny_mce_src.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, tinymce, textarea

I want to used extended Textarea from tiny_mce_src.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<%using(Ajax.BeginForm("CreateArticle","Home",new AjaxOptions(UpdateTargetId="content" }))
  {% <div><p><label for="body"></label> <%= Html.TextArea("body", new style="height:500px"})%></p>  <input type="submit value="Save"/></div> <%}%>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({mode:"textareas", thene:"advanced" }): 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`tinyMCE.init` need to be inside `script` tag:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>       tinyMCE.init({mode:"textareas",thene:"advanced"}); 
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is the misspelling of *theme*?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      tinyMCE.init({mode:"textareas",theme:"advanced"}); 
</script>
```